# C# count of timespan within a timespan

Tags: c#, timespan

I would like to know a way to do this in C#

Let's say I have 2 timespans : TS1 is 3h and TS2 is 12h.

What is the fastest way to calculate how many times TS1 can go within TS2?
In that case, the output would be 4.

if TS1 is 8 days and TS2 is 32 days, it would return 4 as well.

Comment: And if TS1 = 3h and TS2 = 13:05 ? Please give good examples.

Comment: Please check the last sentence, I think you mistyped in "...TS2 is 32 days"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use integer division.  But the devil is in the details, be sure to use an integral property of a TimeSpan to avoid overflow and round-off problems:

```
 int periods = (int)(TS1.Ticks / TS2.Ticks);
```

Answer (score 8):

Integer division?

```
(int) TS1.TotalMilliseconds/(int) TS2.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: @Hans, you can make a case that using `Ticks` is better, and I up-voted you.  But there is no sign the OP cares about sub-millisecond precision.  In fact, the smallest unit he uses is an hour.

Comment: Well, I agree and +1 one for pointing out integer division.  You could have used TimeSpan.TotalHours following that logic though, I only posted to point out the 'fall into the pit of success' angle.

Answer (score 4):

You can divide the `TotalMilliseconds` from one by the other.  That is:

```
double times = TS2.TotalMilliseconds / TS1.TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

int count = (int)(ts2.TotalSeconds / ts1.TotalSeconds);